# Stop javascript slideshow after one loop

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have a custom js slideshow that has settings for animation, true or false, but no option to stop the animation after one loop. The answers I've seen to similar questions here so far have not fit. Any suggestions how I could make that happen? Thank you so much for any tips. Current code below:

```
if ( settings.slideshow && slides_number > 1 ) {
            $slider.hover( function() {
                $slider.addClass( 'slider_hovered' );

                if ( typeof slider_timer != 'undefined' ) {
                    clearInterval( slider_timer );
                }
            }, function() {
                $slider.removeClass( 'slider_hovered' );

                slider_auto_rotate();
            } );
        }

        slider_auto_rotate();

        function slider_auto_rotate(){
            if ( settings.slideshow && slides_number > 1 && ! $slider.hasClass( 'slider_hovered' ) ) {
                slider_timer = setTimeout( function() {
                    $slider.slider_move_to( 'next' );
                }, settings.slideshow_speed );
            }
        }


        $slider.slider_move_to = function ( direction ) {
            var $active_slide = $slide.eq( active_slide ),
                $next_slide;

            $slider.animation_running = true;

            if ( direction == 'next' || direction == 'previous' ){

                if ( direction == 'next' )
                    active_slide = ( active_slide + 1 ) < slides_number ? active_slide + 1 : 0;
                else
                    active_slide = ( active_slide - 1 ) >= 0 ? active_slide - 1 : slides_number - 1;

            } else {

                if ( active_slide == direction ) {
                    $slider.animation_running = false;
                    return;
                }

                active_slide = direction;

            }

            if ( typeof slider_timer != 'undefined' )
                clearInterval( slider_timer );

            $next_slide = $slide.eq( active_slide );
```

Comment: Could you edit out all the bits of code you don't need in order to replicate the problem? It would make your question much more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `slider_auto_rotate()` function like so:

```
function slider_auto_rotate(){
    if ( settings.slideshow && slides_number > 1 && ! $slider.hasClass( 'slider_hovered') && ! slider.hasClass( 'slider_final' ) ) {
        slider_timer = setTimeout( function() {
            $slider.slider_move_to( 'next' );
        }, settings.slideshow_speed );
    }
}
```

Then just add the class `slider_final` to whatever slide you want to stop on, as a note though this will stop the slider at that point rather than after a loop, if you want to stop after a single loop that's a fair bit more complicated since your loop is being done via framework (jQuery in this case) and thus can't have an incremented value added in. It would require you to essentially add a setting for max slides then add a whole function for counting. The above example could be something as simple as just adding the first slide as the last slide with this class to 'fake' a full loop and is fairly quick.

Comment: This seems like a great solution, but I am unsure how to "add the class slider_final to whatever slide you want to stop on". The slides are added through an interface and when I look in the console, there do not seem to be any associated IDs. How would I add this class to the final (or 1st) slide? Thank you so much for helping a js newbie-

Comment: I'd need a fair bit more information to be able to help with that, things like what plugin/script are you using, what are the blocks it's outputting, etc. There's just no where near enough information here to get into that.